# How do i run a program with arguments and as administrator using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, cmd, registry, contextmenu

I have a script that has to launch my program with parameters, and yes it works, here it is.

```
powershell.exe -Command "Start-Process -Verb RunAs -FilePath cmd.exe -Args /C, '\"%1\"'"
```

But when I replace `%1` with my custom parameters program don't want to work anymore.
I replace it with these parameters

```
takeown.exe /F "C:\Users\WobbyChip\Desktop\New folder" /R /D Y & icacls.exe "C:\Users\WobbyChip\Desktop\New folder" /grant Everyone:F /T
```

And now I have this script that doesn't work.

```
powershell.exe -Command "Start-Process -Verb RunAs -FilePath cmd.exe -Args /C, '\"takeown.exe /F "C:\Users\WobbyChip\Desktop\New folder" /R /D Y & icacls.exe "C:\Users\WobbyChip\Desktop\New folder" /grant Everyone:F /T\"'"
```

For more information I launch this script from a registry context menu, it looks like this. But there is no difference launch from the registry or somewhere else. Result is same.

[image]

And the most interesting is that my Hide script works, but Permissions not. Here is the Hide script

```
powershell.exe -Command "Start-Process -Verb RunAs -FilePath attrib.exe -Args +h, +s, '\"%1\"'"
```

Something interesting, while I was trying to fix this I get this error in CMD, but I have no idea what that means and how to fix it.

[image]

Comment: Why not just launch PowerShell (or cmd.exe) as administrator and then just run the commands you want?

Comment: I believe registry values can't take more than 252 chars

Comment: First, I checked through PprocessExplorer and PowerShell ran with all parameters, second this is a function that allows me to do this thing with every folder that I want using variable %1 in the registry

Comment: %1 is used to indicate the first argument you supply to the script via outside the script. Aka in command line it would be `script.ps1 argument1` where argument1 would be %1. Try changing the shortcut to include the argument. Otherwise just set the shortcut properties to admin rights or whatnot and run the script as needed. Also make sure only an admin can alter the script.

Comment: I don't use shortcuts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested quoting gets complicated, and your command is lacking proper escaping of embedded `"` chars.

Try the following, which should work from both `cmd.exe` and from a context-menu command definition in the registry:

```
powershell.exe -Command Start-Process -Verb RunAs cmd.exe -Args /C, 'takeown.exe /F \"C:\Users\WobbyChip\Desktop\New folder\" /R /D Y "&" icacls.exe \"C:\Users\WobbyChip\Desktop\New folder\" /grant Everyone:F /T'
```

- Optional quoting is omitted where possible, so as to minimize the need for nested quoting.
- `'...'` is interpreted by PowerShell as a string literal, as usual.
- `"` chars. that should be preserved as such - even inside `'...'` - must be escaped as `\"`.
- `&` is escaped as `"&"` to prevent `cmd.exe` from interpreting it (you don't strictly need this in the registry); PowerShell later strips these double quotes, because they're not `\`-escaped.